# Get information out of an exe program. Reading memory / injection. Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get information out of an exe program. I have tried to read the memory, but can't seem to find the memory address (As its a position). The tutorials i have watched tell me to use a program called Cheat Engine, but I don't know the exact value of the item.

Also tried injection, but I have no idea what to write to get the variable values.

Been with this problem for a month now (Not searching for the answer really actively).
Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheat engine allows you to make filters that narrow down the memory location, and with enough passes through, you will be able to find the memory location you want. You can also filter through ranges, likely values, and exclude values you know can't be the right ones. If you have any information about what the value is, no matter how poor that information is, Cheat Engine will allow you to narrow that down. Even if it's only "it hasn't changed since last snapshot" or "it's not 3".

Modifying those values should be possible using kernel32 on Windows. I made this project a while back that does memory reading of an online game to compile statistics. Here's a link if that may be helpful to you. For that project I did use Cheat engine to find the positions.

https://github.com/Acebulf/HockeyStatsExtractor

The memory management parts are in Classes/MemoryExtractor.cs

Comment: Thank you it worked(Though it took some time to figure it out).